# How to change rounded corner in viewpager2 Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-viewpager2

Hey I am working in viewpager 2 in android. I want to give rounded corner in view pager 2 but it's not working. Can someone guide me

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
     android:id="@+id/galleryPager"
     android:background="@drawable/round_drawable"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="224dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**round_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="26dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
</shape>
```

UPDATE

I used **RecyclerView.Adapter** inside my viewpager adapter and item xml look like this

**viewpager_item_layout.xml** is used in **reyclerview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery_placeholder"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**viewpager.xml** is my main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/galleryContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
             android:id="@+id/galleryPager"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="224dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
             app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It look like this now. I marked all four side, it looks like there is transparent on it something.

[image]

Note:

I am not using fragment inside my viewpager, instead I am using reyclerview adapter inside my viewpager.adapter

Answer (score 0):

Use round background for your elements inside viewpager not particulary viewpager

For example you have 2 fragment inside view pager and every fragment contain linear layout inside,
Use rounded backgroud for those linear layout
If you need example tell me:))

Comment: I used reyclerview inside and I tried it's not working. Please have a look on my Update

Comment: Can you draw something what kind of shape at end you need!?  Why put only recycleview inside viewpager!?usually inside viewpager fragment or single items will be added, please draw your finall and desired shape

Comment: I need my viewpager to be rounded corner but problem is there is some transparent color is showing in rectangle in all side. Please have a look on above attach. I didn't put reyclerview in my viewpager. My viewpager adapter is extend in reyclerviewer.adapter.  I am not using pageradapter.

Comment: Can you put background color for viewpager same as its own background color? By this trick you can omit that unwanted color

Comment: its not changing color. I tried already this thing

Answer (score 0):

The `viewPager` page fragment will obscure the background of the `ViewPager` as it is drawn on top of it; if you want to force that you have to use a transparent background on the root layout of them by setting `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: i tried your solution. But It didn't work . Please have a look on my Update block

Comment: @vivekmodi sorry a bit confused, is the layout you shared the page of the ViewPager, or the is it a row item of the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: `viewpager.xml` is main activity layout and I used reyclerview.adapter inside my viewpager adapter and layout of adpater is `viewpager_item_layout.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Solved. CardView can be used to clip the corners of a ViewPager or ViewPager2 and create rounded corners.

Like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="115dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I only need top two conners, so i set the card a little bit longer than viewpager.